# Force menu button in Android Lolipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

I have a HTC One M8 with the 5.0 ROM (Play Edition) flashed on it. It's rooted.

I previously used VenomRoms which had an option to force the menu button, is there something similar on the default Lolipop rom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, I assume you mean stock? Then no. Google did away with the menu button in Android 4.0. It's officially unsupported and appears (now called the "Action Overflow button") only when an app ignores design guidelines and requires it anyway. Google provides no direct way to force it, as it's officially no longer a part of Android.

Only custom ROMs or toolkit like Xposed modules can bring it back. An example module that includes such information is [App Settings](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.mods.appsettings), although I can't speak to its Lollipop compatibility, especially since I think Xposed is still in early beta for Lollipop.

Comment: Can you link to Google's documentation on removing the menu button? I am interested in their logic behind this, especially on phones with it built in...

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

The basic rationale is strong: burying commands in a menu key nobody remembers is there (most users don't even know what it is) only creates confusion and reduces functionality. Android took a MASSIVE step forward when they removed this. A very important one. I don't miss it, and I'm very happy apps have mostly stopped relying on it. And very few phones have it anymore. It's a rare annoyance when one appears. Most switched to the multitasking button.

Answer (score 1):

Long press the recent apps button, and you'll get the app menu. At least, that's what works on LG lollipop phones.